# Split String using lua

Tags: java, string, lua

I need a lua code to split a youtube  page line and get the youtube video title and ID .

So I need to extract using lua the id :`r8ocUWwuJDg`
and the title : `"Farsa cu camera ascunsa / Tentatiile soldatilor"`
form a String like the next one

```
</div><div class="yt-lockup-content"><h3 class="yt-lockup-title"><a href="/watch?v=r8ocUWwuJDg" class=" yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2 yt-uix-sessionlink     spf-link " data-sessionlink="itct=CMwBEJQ1GAYiEwia-4r23Z7FAhVD3xwKHSUQAKQojh4yCmctaGlnaC1yZWM" title="Farsa cu camera ascunsa / Tentatiile soldatilor" aria-describedby="description-id-58700" dir="ltr">Farsa cu camera ascunsa / Tentatiile soldatilor</a>
```

How can do this in lua ?How to split the text and get the title and ID?
Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this kind of job should be done with a parser, not pattern matching.

Still, this should work:

```
local str = [[
</div><div class="yt-lockup-content"><h3 class="yt-lockup-title"><a href="/watch?v=r8ocUWwuJDg" class=" yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2 yt-uix-sessionlink     spf-link " data-sessionlink="itct=CMwBEJQ1GAYiEwia-4r23Z7FAhVD3xwKHSUQAKQojh4yCmctaGlnaC1yZWM" title="Farsa cu camera ascunsa / Tentatiile soldatilor" aria-describedby="description-id-58700" dir="ltr">Farsa cu camera ascunsa / Tentatiile soldatilor</a>
]]

local id = str:match('<a href="/watch%?v=(.-)"')
print(id)

local title = str:match('title="(.-)"')
print(title)
```

Note that `-` is used for lazy repetitions.

Comment: You great ! what is '%' for ? In str:match('<a href="/watch%?v=(.-)"') . I tried string.match( line, "watch?v=(.-)\"") and I received errors without '%' before the '?'  . What does '%' ?

Comment: @MariaGheorghe `?` is a magic character in Lua patterns, it must be escaped with `%` to match the character `?` itself. See [Patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1).

Comment: Can you please look at this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979650/close-lua-state-and-reopen