# Close Lua State and Reopen

Tags: android, lua

I'm using Lua in android but is not very clear if I can do this:

```
LuaState L = null;

function loaddata(String data)
{
 if ( L !=null && L.isClosed() == false) 
    L.close();

 L = LuaStateFactory.newLuaState();
 L.openLibs();
 L.LdoString(data);
}

loaddata(string_1)  ;
//and later 
loaddata(string_2);
```

I want to clear the L and use it with another data, `string_2`.
Will my function `L.LdoString(data);` have a new data corresponding to `string_2`?
Or will it be `string_1` plus `string_2` in the `L`?

Comment: If you don't create a new state then anything created by the first string will still exist in the state (global variables, global functions, modified default libraries, etc.).

Comment: After many tests i see the data is cleared , but I'm not sure if I really need the L.close() from the function , or not

Comment: Ah. I'd missed the `L.close()` call there. Yes, that call (given that you need to follow it by creating an entirely new state) is closing the state and you are creating a new state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code when you call `L.close()` you are closing the existing lua state.

You then use `LuaStateFactory.newLuaState()` to create a new (clean) lua state.

Nothing from a previous call to that function will exit in the new state.

(I'm assuming the functions here work as they would appear to and as the C api functions of similar names function.)